# HtmlAttributes on ASP.NET MVC 3 with Razor view in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html

Can anybody tell me how do I add this htmlAttribute on MVC 3 Razor view?

```
New With {.watermark = "sometext", .title = "sometext"}
```

I tried the C# way but it's not working (@watermark) but it's not working.

Thanks.

UPDATE here is the current usage I am trying but it's not working.

```
  @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.FirstName, New With {.maxlength = "50"})
```

This isn't working either

```
 @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.FirstName, New Object() {"maxlength=50"})
```

Bear in mind that I am doing this on vb.net.
PLEEASE HELP!

Comment: What do you mean under adding htmlAttribute on View?

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify your question a bit and post a longer code sample of what you're trying to do. It's not clear what you're asking as HtmlAtttibutes would be applied to some HtmlHelper methods in the view, but not the view itself.

Comment: `<a href='' title="sometext" watermark="sometext">link</a>` it appears to result in a proper addition of htmlAttributes - what is your problem exactly?

Comment: @BuildStarted: This is working on MVC 2 but not on MVC 3.
@Craig M & @archil: By HtmlAttibutes I mean to the view itself.

Comment: @Besnik, I exclusively use MVC 3. Post the rest of your code so that we can see if there are other issues preventing it from working properly.

Comment: @BuildStarted please check it out and let me know how are you doing it.

Comment: Well, you didn't have the `EditorFor` and that changes everything. You should use `@Html.TextBoxFor` instead. Editor for looks for a template rather than using the built in textbox. (assuming you want a textbox)

Comment: If you really want to use `EditorFor` I suggest you read http://aspadvice.com/blogs/kiran/archive/2009/11/29/Adding-html-attributes-support-for-Templates-_2D00_-ASP.Net-MVC-2.0-Beta_2D00_1.aspx

Comment: `@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.FirstName, New With {.maxlength = "50"})` will work just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Just crossed all over the internet for the answer to this and tripped on the solution myself. Granted the site I'm working on isn't live yet, but so far this solution is working for me. Here is the exact line of code that I wrote and is working for me:

```
@Html.CheckBox("chb", item.isAuditor, New With {.disabled = "disabled",  .tabIndex = "3"})
```

That piece of code is in a for each loop which is processing each "item" is the list passed to the view by the controller.

Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. i was originally writing the code like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.CostCentreID, ViewData("ListOfCostCentres"), New With {.size = "20"})
```

but this was not working. but the following way work, i guess because we need to typecast `ViewData` before we can use it.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.CostCentreID, CType(ViewData("ListOfCostCentres"), SelectList), New With {.size = "20"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Besnik,

To add attributes in vbhtml to your markup, use the following as an example:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.FirstName, New Object() { "title" = "sometext", "watermark" = "sometext")
```

counsellorben

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

`@Html.TextBox("TextBoxName", New With {.maxlength = 3})`